# Не совсем понимаю как спарсить данный из response (Ниже на фото) Парсер нужен на Питоне

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно спарсить данный а именно "id" "name" "owner"

Comment: Код, ошибки, данные и так далее - текстом, не картинкой. Свои вопросы, ошибки, желаемое поведение программы - нужно описывать в теме, а не заголовке. А теперь мои вопросы: где ваши попытки решения? Что конкретно вызывает трудности?

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема, у вас массив, просто пройдитесь по нему, и сохраните ваши данные куда-нибудь в какой-нибудь список объектов

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests as rs

data = rs.reg('ссылка на сайт').json()

ndata = {}
for i in data['houses']['hasOwner']:
    ndata[i['id']] = [i['name'], i['owner']]

print(data)
```

Результат:

```
{1:['Пудж Вашингтон', 'Pudzh_Vashington'],...
```

Comment: @СергейШ маленькую правку можно предложить , если она не сильно меняет смысл ответа;)